# How to reuse an intent and bring it to the front?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a HashMap  to keep track of my running intents; every time I start a new intent that runs a custom `ChatActivity` class, I save it to the HashMap.

The intents remain active (I dont use `finish()` on them); I want to be able to bring one of them 'back' so that every view and information I had changed while that intent was activated, will still be there.

I had tried using flags in various forms like below with no success.

```
Intent intent = data.getDictionary().get(getName(position));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

It seems that when I use flags nothing happens, and when I don't use it, it just starts a new activity from fresh (not my desired behavior).

I suspect that my problems rises from the fact that all my intents run the same class, but I will let you be the judge of that.

Thank you.

Comment: anyone? :(
I really dont want to reload all the data every time..

Comment: do you have any other flags set on the original intent?

Comment: oh sorry never mind, you used setFlags not addFlags

Comment: No.
All the intents are started with no flags.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this one in your manifest file : `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

According to the doc:

> If, when starting the activity, there is already an instance of the
>   same activity class in the foreground that is interacting with the
>   user, then re-use that instance. This existing instance will receive a
>   call to Activity.onNewIntent() with the new Intent that is being
>   started.